# In Asp.net core, UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute causes Error 404 when application is started

Tags: asp.net-core, error-handling

I used app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute to catch the statuscode error and  I am using other middleware for my application exception handling. But when I start my application, Error control action method is invoked with 404 statuscode.

If I comment app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute and use my middle ware exception handling then the application is started without error but after some time if i give wrong url then 404 error is not cached by my middle ware exception handling. My findings are 404 error is caught by using app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute but it throws error when application is started.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?statusCode={0}");

            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            app.UseCors(x => 
                       x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthentication();


            app.UseMvc();
     }
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your `ExceptionMiddleware` and you controller handling the error logic (from the "/Error" route)?

Comment: Check your network tab to see whether there is any resouce is not found. Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.